# How to make rdoc link to a method with equal sign

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, documentation, metaprogramming, rdoc

In one file I have

```
module Adapter
  ##
  # :method: avatar

  ##
  # :method: avatar=(value)
end
```

In another file I want to have links to these methods:

```
# Adapter#avatar         # this generates a valid link to another page
# Adapter#avatar=        # this is shown as raw text
```

How to tell rdoc that it should generate the second link?

Update: it's confirmed that if the writer is defined statically with `def avatar=(value); end`, the link is generated okay. Dynamic writer though is apparently bugged.

Update2: Okay, it's not about the link. It's about generating right name of the writer method:

```
module Adapter
  ##
  # :method: avatar=(value)
end
```

generated doc with `avatar=(value)()` name, and

```
module Adapter
  def avatar=(value); end
end
```

generates correct `avatar=(value)` doc which gets linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should declare your parameters using `:call-seq:`**, and not include your parameter list in the `:method:` line. The following works for me, and all the links work:

```
module Adapter
  ##
  # :method: avatar

  ##
  # :method: avatar=
  #
  # :call-seq: avatar=(value)
end

# See Adapter#avatar  
# See Adapter#avatar=
#
class Linked
end
```

`:method:` declares the *name* of the method, and `:call-seq:` declares the parameter signature it accepts.

(And BTW, I found some very helpful documentation on RDoc syntax [here](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html)).

Comment: I can't define the method, it's dynamic. And the one without '=' is linked fine.

Comment: @ujifgc you can, but make sure you declare before dynamic generation happens. Dynamic generation (define_method for example) can overrode these empty methods...

Comment: So I define one method for rdoc and then dynamically create another one with different name, and I get two methods where I must have only the dynamic one. Right?

Comment: Aha, I think I got it. You need to use `:call-seq:`, and that makes all the links work and the methods show up without extra `()` characters. I've rewritten my answer, please check again

Comment: I would also mention, if you're just starting to write documentation and are interested in alternatives, I really prefer [YARD](http://yardoc.org) over RDoc.

Comment: Excellent, `:call-seq:` fixed everything.